# how to authenticate encrypted password in doctrine 1.1.4 with zend framework 1.9.0?

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine

when i remove **PASSWORD(?)** and place **?** than it works !

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
      ->from('Admanusp_Model_User u')
      ->where('u.Username = ? AND u.Password = PASSWORD(?)',
                array($this->username, $this->password)
        );
```

Thank You !

Comment: How is your password stored in database? Is it hashed or somehting?

Comment: At this moment password is **"param"**, i need to store it hashed, **PASSWORD(?)** might be make it encrypted and query gets fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to hash your passwords first in database before fetching them in your application.

There are many ways of storing passwords in database. You probably should use hashing with salt on production environment, however - to simplyfy things, I suppose you'll be using just MD5().

As you wrote on comment, your users table contains plain text passwords. Let's convert them into MD5 hashes invoking query below:

```
UPDATE user SET Password = MD5(Password)
```

Now you can check if given user data are correct with this Doctrine query:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from('Admanusp_Model_User u')
    ->where('u.Username = ? AND u.Password = ?',
            array($this->username, md5($this->password))
    );
```

I don't recommend you to put plain text password in your query, like:

```
->where('u.Username = ? AND u.Password = MD5(?), array($this->username, $this->password));
```

because those passwords can be saved then in DBMS or profiler logs.

Another things is you shouldn't use MySQL PASSWORD() function, according to the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password):

> The PASSWORD() function is used by the authentication system in MySQL
>   Server; you should not use it in your own applications. For that
>   purpose, consider MD5() or SHA1() instead.

Hope those informations will lead you on the right direction.

Comment: Daniel Gadawski thank you for great help, now all things are clear and i am on the way, again thank you !